# what is good/available  Python Interpreter to be integrated  for WPF Application?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

I have  Script Editor Window developed from scratch, which already supports CINT based(C/C++ Scripts), Similarly I need Python Interpreter similar to CINT and could seamlessly integrate into the WPF framework.

Primarily the objective is to support both Scripts(C Scripts & Python as well), which requires an Python Interpreter available Freely or qualifies for LGPL,   Could anyone throw light on the same.

Python Interpreter which should be of open source(LGPL)

Environment: WPF Application Development on Windows 7 O/S(SP 1).

Answer (score 3):

[IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) is an implementation of the Python programming language targeting the .NET Framework and Mono. It is licensed on Apache v2.0 license.

The current release 2.7.1 targets CPython 2.7 and requires .NET 4 or Silverlight 4.

Answer (score 0):

The standard Python interpreter, CPython, fits your description.

http://docs.python.org/license.html